# Do Ionic2 plugins affect initial app loading time?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, hybrid-mobile-app

I have created an Ionic2 app for android mobiles. To implement multiple functionalities I have used various plugins available to serve my requests. My app(production build) takes 13-15 seconds of initial loading time. 
Is this loading time natural for Ionic2 Apps having plugins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes in general they increase it a little but not that much (10+ sec). The problem you encounter probably is that your application runs in development mode.

To build it in production mode use the `--prod` command line flag. (You should see the line `ngc started...` in the console.)

On the one hand this will decrease the bundle size & increase the performance of your app a lot, on the other hand it will become harder to debug your applications in the browser, as now it's compiled.